# AsyncTask onPostExecute() too slow

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am using AsyncTask to analyse some data and keep the UI running smoothly.
However, the return value takes way too long to come back.

Event:
A ball goes across the screen. at point x there is a lot of analysis done. i would like the ball to change colour as a result of point x's calculations. In testing the ball changes colour about a second (or just less) after point x.

I currently get my result back from this:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
MotionView.hitCorrectNote = result;
}
```

Can I not return a value from the method:

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... var)
```

surely I can if it is type Boolean?

Any other suggestions about how to speed this up would be welcome.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what the actual problem is. If the background task is performing a long running operation then yes, the doPostExecute will be called delayed. I don't think that there is a huge delay between return of `doInBackground` and call of `onPostExecute`...

Comment: You might get better performance and more fine-grained control by doing this with something other than AsyncTask - a background thread (it can sleep when it's not processing data) updating the UI via a Handler would probably work better.

Comment: I do need it to update the UI though, or at least return a variable back to the UI thread.
I would like to know if i can return a varible from the doinbackground method?

Comment: also would it not be quicker to return a value from the publishPorgress method?

Comment: Maybe you're talking about the AsyncTask's get() method, that waits for AsyncTask to return the value? You can indeed use it, but it turns the asynchronous nature of AsyncTask to synchronous, so this is probably a signal to rethink the design of the implementation.

Comment: I think you do the wrong calculations at the wrong place. Normally such calculations are done on the graphic chip. (If it's something like for instance collision detection)

Comment: I'm seeing about a 1-second delay between the last line of code running in doInBackground and the first line of code running in onPostExecute. So for long operations, it's not noticeable, but if the operation happens to run quickly, this setup makes it noticeably slower than needed. This is a very old question, and I haven't seen other questions like it, but maybe that's what the original poster was seeing.